# Can't see copied Jenkins jobs from one instance to the other in a destination instance folder?

Tags: jenkins

I am copying Jenkins jobs from one instance to the other. I created a folder called "
Old_Jobs" in the destination instance under jobs directory. If I copy all the jobs under this Old_jobs directory and reload configuration from disk, I can't see those jobs in the Jenkins GUI. However, if I copy those jobs under the "jobs" directory, I can see all the jobs in Jenkins GUI.

Is there any way I can see all my copied jobs under /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Old_Jobs/ directory?

Note- I have tried changing permission to 777 in the destination folder, but it didn't work.
Ownership is also correct in the destination instance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, all the jobs are listed under /jobs/
Since you have created one more directory, "Old_Jobs" under /jobs, the required structure is not present.

Also, I remember facing similar issue (even with keeping same directory structure) and I had to copy "/workspace" folder as well to the new instance.

You can refer required directory structure over here : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

[image]

It also mentioned below points:

> Moving/copying/renaming jobs You can:
>
> 1. Move a job from one installation of Jenkins to another by simply copying the corresponding job directory.
> 2. Make a copy of an existing job by making a clone of a job directory by a different name.
> 3. Rename an existing job by renaming a directory. Note that the if you change a job name you will need to change any other job that tries
>      to call the renamed job.
>
> Those operations can be done even when Jenkins is running. For changes
>   like these to take effect, you have to click "reload config" to force
>   Jenkins to reload configuration from the disk.